# how can i get the specific info about a user

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

i'm working on a web app in which a user can create an address when logged in, how can i get the current logged in user address which was created by the user

these my address route

```
const router = require("express").Router();
const Address = require("../models/address");
const User = require("../models/user");


const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken");

router.get('/addresses', (req, res, next) => {
  let token = req.headers.token; //token
  jwt.verify(token, 'secretkey', (err, decoded) => {
    if (err) return res.status(401).json({
      title: 'unauthorized'
    })
    //token is valid
    Address.findOne({ _id: decoded.addressId }, (err, user) => {
      if (err) return console.log(err)
      return res.status(200).json({
        title: 'adress  grabbed',
        address: {
          streetAddress: user.streetAddress,
          fullName: user.fullName
        }
      })
    })

  })
})
```

i get unauthorised any time i want to get the address of the current user

my db schema

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const AddressSchema = new Schema({
  user: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "User" },
  country: String,
  fullName: String,
  streetAddress: String,
  city: String,
  state: String,
  zipCode: Number,
  phoneNumber: String,
  deliverInstructions: String,
  securityCode: String
});

module.exports = mongoose.model("Address", AddressSchema);
```

my auth route to get details of current user

````
//grabbing user info
router.get('/auth/user', (req, res, next) => {
  let token = req.headers.token; //token
  jwt.verify(token, 'secretkey', (err, decoded) => {
    if (err) return res.status(401).json({
      title: 'unauthorized'
    })
    //token is valid
    User.findOne({ _id: decoded.userId }, (err, user) => {
      if (err) return console.log(err)
      return res.status(200).json({
        title: 'user grabbed',
        user: {
          email: user.email,
          name: user.name
        }
      })
    })

  })
})```

please how can i go about it
````